# Gimp : rescale colors for rendering only

Tags: gimp

I have to work with grayscale `.pfm` (Portable Bitmap) images that apparently Gimp can open.
However, values are way higher than 1, like in range `[1;280]`. So every pixel appears white, with % values for red, green and blue like 150%.

How can I rescale Gimp colors for rendering **only**, like a pixel with value `280.0` will be white and a pixel `1.0` black ?

Comment: Can you post a sample file somewhere? According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#32-bit_extensions) the third line of the file is the range used (so if `280.0` is white, the third line of your file should be `280.0` or `-280.0` depending on endianness).

Comment: Of course, here is the link: https://ufile.io/iinl2cdj (8Mo, too big for SE). I don't remember if the range is really `[1.0;280.0]` but it should be something like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a levels adjustment to stretch the colours out. All the detail seems to be crushed up in the whites. Whether or not this is the desired result I can't be sure, but there's definitely an image in there.

Do *Colors > Levels* and drag the tiny black arrow in the Input Levels all the way to the right

[image]

Comment: I just need for roughly visualizing if the result looks like something and is not random data. The scene are random object so its normal to be a little "messed-up"

Answer (score 1):

Your file has a range line (3rd line) that says `-1.000000` so the indicated range isn't coherent with the encoded values if they can go up to 280.

Replacing (with an hex editor) the `-1.000000` with `-280.0000` (same endianness) does yield a useful result (all white), but using `280.00000` (opposite endianness) yields this:

[image]

Comment: You're right. The images are used for deep learning. The neural network don't use the range in the header so it will always be let at `-1`, but it can mess up gimp.